# Does the property $a\neq a$ exist somewhere in mathematics?

Tags: abstract-algebra, analysis

Whenever I read about properties of the real numbers, I'm always presented the property $a=a$ sometime ago I didn't know why they stated such obvious properties but then, after reading some abstract algebra, my guess is that those obvious properties are put there for comparison with other mathematical concepts.

So reading this property I thought: Are there properties such as $a\neq a$, $a<a$ or $a>a$ in some mathematical field of study? If not, why is the importance of stating $a=a$?

Comment: A lot of relations we want to be reflexive (i.e. $a\sim a$). But if we don't *state* that it's reflexive, then our definitions allow for nonreflexiveness! It's this way with *all* axiomatic or definitional situations: you're completely transparent about what properties you desire. The only time you omit a condition is if it goes without saying, and when we're talking about relations *in general* reflexiveness does not go without saying. Thus, the importance of stating $a\sim a$ follows from the generic importance of not hiding information from your reader.

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer this question... I don't think there's even an axiom that says a=a, it's just assumed that if a is a constant it stays the same. Where did you see "a=a" stated as a property of real numbers (I'm not saying it's not, just that I don't recall ever seeing the statement being explicitly made)?

Comment: Keep in mind that a "property" (the technical term is *relation*) is just a meaning we assign to a symbol.  So there are certainly relations that satisfy the sort of identities you describe, but we typically don't use the symbols "=", "<", or ">" to describe them as that would be needlessly confusing.

Comment: Presumably nobody would be nutty enough to use the symbol $=$ to refer to a non-reflexive relation.

Comment: Sure, consider the set of all humans alive and the "=" sign represents the relation "the child of" so a=b means a is the child of b. Clearly "a=a" won't hold for anyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the standard formulation of mathematics, $a = a$ is taken as a logical axiom.  This fits with the interpretation of "$=$" as "equals", because as a matter of fact everything is equal to itself (I mean that this is true as a statement in the English language.)

Of course there are some non-reflexive properties studied in mathematics, but we wouldn't use the symbol "=" for them, because it is already taken.  We also wouldn't use similar symbols such as "$\approx$", because such symbols connote reflexivity.

To address your question about why $a = a$ is even worth mentioning, one reason is that by explicitly pointing out properties of equality (such as reflexivity) we may then consider the question of which *other* relations have such properties.  For example, the notion of equivalence relations (reflexive, symmetric, and transitive relations) is very useful but would be difficult to motivate without the observation that equality itself is an equivalence relation.